# Не получается поменять тип столбца

Tags: sql

Вот мой sql:

```
UPDATE [Table_COPY] SET [Column] = NULL
GO
ALTER TABLE [Table_COPY] ALTER COLUMN [Column] image
```

Column сейчас типа float
При выполнении команды возникает ошибка - Operand type clash: float is incompatible with image

Comment: Ну несовместимые типы. Если уж Вы зачистили данные - просто дропните поле и создайте новое, с тем же именем и нужным типом.

Comment: @Akina DROP COLUMN [Column] ADD [Column] image. Вот-так?

Comment: Конечно, а как иначе-то.

Comment: @Akina А как изменить порядок столбцов? Ну сейчас он первый, а после выполнения команд он станет последним. А мне надо чтобы он был первым.

Comment: А зачем? всё равно Вы к нему обращаетесь по имени - так какая разница, где именно он расположен?

Comment: @Akina Ну у меня выводиться таблица в програмvе на WPF. И это столбец идет первым

Comment: Отличный повод отвыкнуть от плохого. Забудьте про звезду, указывайте в запросе по отдельности имена всех полей в нужном порядке. Звезду используйте только в одном случае - в `COUNT(*)`.

Comment: @Akina Хорошо, а в принципе можно изменить порядок столбцов?

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sql/relational-databases/tables/change-column-order-in-a-table?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: @Akina поняла то-есть нельзя с помощью SQL

Comment: да. Только пересозданием таблицы.

Comment: @Akina а можно сделать без drop?

Comment: Ну если Вы сможете построить цепочку совместимых преобразований (типа, скажем, сперва float в decimal, потом в integer, потом в string... ну и наконец доберётесь до image) - то можно. Вот справка: https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-conversion-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver15 - вроде можно в качестве промежуточного использовать varbinary.

Comment: [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=eace59fdd1e5b997202bb1ec9e9cf301) утверждает, что преобразование выполняется успешно.